Запятая на стыке союзов что, кто
Подскажите, пожалуйста, верно ли понимаю:
Ему было ясно, что, кто первый выбьется из сил, тот окажется за бортом — в этом предложении на стыке союзов должна стоять запятая, поскольку слово тот — не вторая часть союза, а указательное местоимение в главном предложении при придаточной части 'кто первый выбьется из сил'?

Верно понимаете, знаки на месте, но требуется редактура (если это допустимо).
Избавляемся от столпотворения запятых:
Ему было ясно: кто первый выбьется из сил, тот окажется за бортом.

Большое спасибо за ответ, хотелось удостовериться, не напутал ли чего мозг:)
